# Elastic Search listening only on IPv6 [CentOS]

Tags: centos7, elasticsearch

I've installed Elastic Search 1.7.4 on CentOS 7.2 this way:

```
wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.4.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh elasticsearch-1.7.4.noarch.rpm
```

The service is started and ES works (verified with curl), however, it only listens to IPv6 with default configuration. netstat -na gives me the following:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Using nmap from other servers I see that ports 9200 and 9300 are filtered, firewall is disabled.

Editing /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and setting:

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

doesn't change anything. Setting this to the external IPv4 address of the server does add the additional two entries in netstat -na output, but I need ES to be accessible to my local network, so this is useless and netstat still registers this as tcp6.

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.54:9200       :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.54:9300       :::*                    LISTEN
```

setting:

```
network.bind_host: _eth0:ipv4_
```

Causes ES to bind to the local IPv4 and then it is of course only available from the local server. Omitting the "ipv4" part causes ES to bind to IPv6 address of the NIC.

How do I enable ES to bind to IPv4? I have no alternative, my network is IPv4 only and I have to use this old version of ES because I'm running some applications that require this version.

Comment: what's the output of `ip addr`

Comment: 2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b4:6c:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.54/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb4:6cf7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: try `network.bind_host: _enp0s3:ipv4_` ?


or use `network.host: _non_loopback_` and remove `network.bind_host` and `network.publish_host`

Comment: @JacobEvans already tried, it binds to IPv4, but then ES is available only from localhost. It should bind to 0.0.0.0

Comment: that is really strange, I would try removing all network.bind options, and then install with the yum repo file instead of the RPM, never had this issue with a few hundred ES Servers built.

Comment: "filtered" means just that. Check your firewall again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is freshly installed CentOS VM, no firewall was installed and I checked that iptables and ufw are not present. I can SSH into the machine. Unless I'm missing something this isn't a firewall issue

Comment: A freshly installed CentOS _does_ have a running firewall by default. See [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html) to learn how to configure it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That was it! I guess I'm spending too much time with Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [unix exchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237747/52243)

> This is happening because by default, AF_INET6 sockets will actually work for both IPv4 and IPv6. See section 3.7 - Compatibility with IPv4 Nodes of RFC 3493 - Basic Socket Interface Extensions for IPv6

But as you've figured out, firewalld is enabled out of the box.

create this file to your `/etc/firewalld/services/elasticsearch.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>Elasticsearch</short>
  <description>Elasticsearch is a distributed, open source search and analytics engine, designed for horizontal scalability, reliability, and easy management.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="9300"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="9200"/>
</service>
```

Update permissions

```
chmod 0400 /etc/firewalld/services/elasticsearch.xml
chown root: /etc/firewalld/services/elasticsearch.xml
```

Run these commands

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=elasticsearch --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Also works for kibana! You could add the kibana port here or create a kibana.xml.

Comment: I would but that's out of scope for the question. :/

Answer (score 2):

This is a common pitfall with ES, because there are *two* network settings that need to be set: `network.bind_host` AND `network.publish_host`. Because of this, the ES devs have added this shortcut:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

I've had some other problems with ES when IPv6 was enabled but not configured so you might want to edit the sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And do `sysctl -p`.

Comment: Why are you recommending to disable IPv6 on the network interfaces? Some of us are in the 21st century and cannot do this. Whatever the problem is, there must be a real solution.

Comment: @MichaelHampton See: https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/issues/596

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem with your network. That indicates that your local host was misconfigured. Leaving everything at its defaults instead of trying to forcibly remove IPv6 from the lo interface (which someone did to that system) would have been fine. I would expect other stuff to break if someone removed 127.0.0.1 from lo as well.

Comment: @MichaelHampton everything was left at the default, there simply was no SLAAC in the network.

Answer (score -2):

Try disabling the firewall that comes pre packed with centos

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/how-to-startstop-or-enabledisable-firewalld-on-centos-7

I recommend a dedicated hardware firewall in front of the machine, I would NOT rely on a software firewall on the machine you are using. If an attacker is hitting the machine, it's already too late.

Comment: I mentioned that a firewall exists. I certainly DO NOT recommend disabling it.

Comment: ok i've taken your credit out.

Comment: Dedicated hardware firewall is not an option for a cheap VPS server and besides, with [supply chain attacks](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2018/10/another_bloombe.html) hitting the news, I'd put more trust in open source software than add another hardware firewall. Not to mention that hardware firewall can have security vulnerabilities. In any case, simply getting rid of a firewall is not a good choice.

Comment: I have a $5 VPS with upcloud, it comes with a dedicated firewall. they manage the firewall and all the security updates.